# IDA Pro only recognizes my files as BINARY

Tags: ida, binary-analysis, ida-plugin, idapro-sdk

I am trying to disassemble some various files, and IDA does not recognize them. Is there anyway to add more file types to IDA Pro? I am running ida 6.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to create a Loader plugin for them. See the `ldr` directory in the IDA Pro SDK.

Once the Loader is built, you would copy it to the `loaders` subdirectory under IDA Pro's directory.

Here's a nice blog entry on writing IDA Pro file loaders in higher level languages: http://www.hexblog.com/?p=110

Comment: @user3119546 You should mark it as a correct answer (to help people looking for similar answers here).